# Customer's locations available in the database. How do I upload customers' locations to devexpress map control

Tags: devexpress

I'm developing a routing program. I need to see the location of registered customers on the map. How do I transfer the locations in the sql database to the devexpres map control.

Comment: Welcome to So! Have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you start from reading the [How to: Automatically Generate Vector Items from a Datasource](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/15220/Controls-and-Libraries/Map-Control/Examples/Vector-Data/Providing-Data/How-to-Automatically-Generate-Vector-Items-from-a-Datasource) help article which provides step-by-step instruction on binding a Map control to data stored in an external XML file, which contains information about wrecked ships, including ship coordinates.
You can adapt the technique demonstrated in this example to your real case.
The complete sample project is available on [GitHub](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/15220/Controls-and-Libraries/Map-Control/Examples/Vector-Data/Providing-Data/How-to-Automatically-Generate-Vector-Items-from-a-Datasource).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'm using new to the map. I'm more inexperienced. I have examined this example but I have not succeeded.